# TypeScript: Correctly handle recursive types

Tags: typescript

### Edit

I got a step further. The more complex example looks like this ([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhFgGIFcB2BjYBLA9qgzlALxQDeAsAFBRQDaA1hCAFxT7ABOWqA5gLqsAFIIB0YgIYce+VuNQhafAJTEAfFDkgVAH1jwkaTLgJUAvlSoAzQ9jxR0ACzk8IcBCgy2CAHgAqUCAAPYAhUABNCNwNPY3xVQTD9DyM8GShfJVZ-Cmp7VOA8sBBiMjERRPcbWNMNSKSq1IBuC1zLHA5BABsIAsZi7kKtMioaGnR8qAA3cU7kaBIK6JSCBiY+ZtyaLEtBadnobnY5dAgcSyhkrxUc0dHxotWQPhLhMslpFSJ1G9u71JxuiJOjgeIIAEQOLBgpQbX6jDg9ZAcVBTGZzUQSKT4GEjX6mHGbKA1CCdfDQH63e4KPrPEiOZyueoxVK7NEQAm3cy5Lm4hHAJEoqm1dIbUxAA)):

```js
type DeepFunctions = {
  [key: string]: ((...args: any[]) => any) | DeepFunctions
}

function changeDeepFunctions<T extends DeepFunctions>(deepFunctions: T): T {
  const copy = {...deepFunctions} as DeepFunctions;

  for(let key in copy) {
    const value = deepFunctions[key];
    if(value instanceof Function) {
      copy[key] = ((...args) => {
        console.log("hi");
        return value(...args);
      });
    } else {
      copy[key] = changeDeepFunctions(value);
    }
  }

  return copy as T;
}
```

Everythings fine and the output is exactly like it should be. However, I don't get why I needed to do it this way. Maybe still someone can help me understand.

### Original Post

I'm kind of new to typescript and I cannot find a good solution for a seemingly easy problem.

All Code you can see here is written down in this [PlayGround](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMbAJYHsEGcoF4oDeAsAFBRQDaA1hCAFxRbABOqCA5gLoMAUAdAICGzdlgaCEICpwCUeAHxQJIANykAvmpKkIADzDpmwKADNEKDAihIAFhPYR4yNJiwAeACpQ9wCAgAmOE4WrvI8Zs6WYlAeMgxexGTWrsZI6GAgeIRQAnwRIdhQmqSk5CaGUDwANhDGNJlspuYu2HKJ5ORp2Mb5WfktWNS0nFodyRlDIJxZPPxCIlhyuIrtY8nY6DV8VejsPABENqj7MqNrzLVwzFb5c3zCoqelHepPSeolSRfAV1ZpGVoPtoSKBIFAACIQCBgYIDLKrSYMJisDjcSp3B7RZTSJaKZRyAA+EKhMOaUQ0n36lmsdg4EEh0NhUU83l0vgCOAZpMioR4-hJTNc8TiMUIzy6THGmXwBFy-MZZNcxWBZUM1VqUHqUEa8u5BUWYqSnRSUAAboIqnBoPhdYLsJMRs9yKgTDxzZboGwmBIkBB0CZYIqEG0nR1-lJ6tN8LNcpjcYa1mHXJsINtdgcjiczonvr8zRarRiFm9E69s0VvFUsNBVmMAPR17XGAC2cElACNoIJiQqeYV0O2AFYQFCh40TSNZWz2ekCoNYN0FiAll7PIHPXPXKWAoA).

Because my real example is a bit too heavy, I reduced it to these (hopefully :)) equal examples:

1. I would like to write a function that gets an object with several functions and map it to an object with mapped functions. Kind of hard to describe, but easy to understand with code:

```js
type Functions = {
  [key: string]: (...args: any[]) => any;
};

export function changeFunctions<T extends Functions>(functions: T): T {
  const copy = { ...functions };

  for (let key in functions) {
    const func = functions[key];
    copy[key] = ((...args) => {
      console.log("hi");
      return func(...args);
    });
  }

  return copy;
}
```

If you have look at the code in the playground, you can see the

```
copy[key] = ...
```

line produces a type error: *Type '(...args: any[]) => any' is not assignable to type 'T[Extract<keyof T, string>]'.(2322)*
It's fixable by adding **as typeof func** at the end of the assignment, but that doesn't feel right.

Is there a clean way to write this?

The second example extends the first, so the solution might be similar:

2. As an extension to 1., the function now should be able to correctly convert objects containing functions, but also recursively contain other objects with functions. Here is the code:

```js
type DeepFunctions = {
  [key: string]: ((...args: any[]) => any) | DeepFunctions
}

function changeDeepFunctions<T extends DeepFunctions>(deepFunctions: T): T {
  const copy = {...deepFunctions};

  for(let key in deepFunctions) {
    const value = deepFunctions[key];
    if(value instanceof Function) {
      copy[key] = ((...args) => {
        console.log("hi");
        return value(...args);
      });
    } else {
      // it must be a DeepFunctions object
      copy[key] = changeDeepFunctions(value);
    }
  }

  return copy;
}
```

As you can see in the playground, the *copy[key]* assignment fails in the same way as in the example above. The other assignment:

```
copy[key] = changeDeepFunctions(value);
```

doesn't raise an error. The type is still wrong, though. Hovering over *value* shows a type of *never*.

Have you any hints how to correctly write such methods in typescript with correct types?

Comment: Do you need to use generics?

Comment: I think so ... It's important that the type of the result is the same than the type of the input.

Comment: The whole thing works if you remove the generic T and use your types directly as input and output of each function . Also, for you DeepFunctions type do you mean
    `type DeepFunctions = {
      [key: string]: ((...args: any[]) => any) | DeepFunctions
    }`
The DeepFunctionms definition needs to be as above for the code to work.

Comment: The definition of DeepFunctions was wrong, that's true. I added the missing braces. Thanks. However, removing the generics (if I got it right, i just removed the generics and the output type) I get no more warnings, but the output type is too unspecific. But maybe I got you wrong?

Comment: No you got me right, extends is a little mysterious for me but I though that change I suggested might either work for you or help someone else figure it out

Comment: I found a possible solution thanks to you. Still not sure why I needed to do it this way. Hopefully someone can help. - I edited the post accordingly.

Comment: I recommend you post this question as an issue on the typescript github. If you get an answer there please update as I am really interested in the explanation.